# When is the page send to clients browser?

Tags: php

When i build a set of  elements (say 100) with php (in a loop)
Is the page send to the client only when the loop is completed or is the page on client side already showing on the client before the loop is completed? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control output to client browser anytime in your PHP code

Example Send to Client Instantly

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i ++) {
    echo $i, " - sent ";
    sleep(1);
    flush(); // Send to client Instantly 
}
```

Example Send after Loop

```
ob_start();
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i ++) {
    echo $i, " - sent ";
    sleep(1);
}
ob_end_flush() // Send after loop
```

Example 3 ( This  would just use your default output buffer configuration )

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i ++) {
    echo $i, " - sent ";
    sleep(1);
}
```

Finally (Credit : Ninsuo)

Some browsers does not display anything until the page is fully loaded so we don't always control flushing

Comment: Exactly. And you may point out that some browsers does not display anything until the page is fully loaded so we don't always control flushing.

Comment: @Baba:This is a nice answer.

I'll use this if necesarry once in figure out how the server is configured (with phpinfo?)

I wonder why you use the sleep() function...

Comment: ah ok, yes sry, the sleep function is to make the loop go slower so i can see the effect... thanx

Comment: because your bandwith speed will not let you know if flush() is working :-)

Comment: @Nomistake that was the idea for using sleep

Answer (score 1):

it depends how your [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) is configured.

You can see the different options [here](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php).

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I think i can use phpinfo to see this setting? (site is on hosted server, i dont manage it)

Comment: Yes, those information are on your phpinfo(). You may search for "output_buffering", "implicit_flush" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you can't rely on anything being shown to the user until the script ends. While you may be able to set PHP's buffering settings, this then will go through Apache which may or may not buffer, and then to the browser, which also may or may not buffer.

The safest way to show the user bits of data when they are available is through AJAX calls from the client browser after the page has loaded.